# why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question about whether a certain type of computer hardware exists and it was closed.  As this pertains directly to computer hardware and has an easily definable answer I do not see why the question was closed.

[Is there an internal wireless broadband card available for Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/264061/58439)

I am not seeking buying recommendations, but if that type of card exists at all.

> and it is not about
>
> videogames or consoles
>
> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
>
> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
>
> a shopping or buying recommendation

The only limit that is close to being applicable is the buying recommendation and I am NOT seeking that advice.

Comment: you are trying to buy a wireless adapter that works in linux but you not asking for a shopping recommendation.... I don't follow the logic.

Comment: @Kyle I am asking if they exist, should I even bother looking into it more, or is my search in vain.  I'm not asking "which of wireless broadband card is the best?"

Comment: @Patrick that's fair I understand what your saying, however you probably need to just edit out any specifics and ask exactly that: "does X hardware exist". I'm not sure if site policy will then allow the question but you will at least get my reopen vote.

Comment: @Kyle I removed the info about my current solution so that the question is just about 3g broadband cards & Linux.

Comment: I'll cast my reopen vote. You might also want to flag for moderator attention and explain that you cleaned it up to be to be just about 3g broadband cards & linux. Otherwise you will have to wait for 3 more reopen votes....

Comment: @Kyle thanks for the vote & the input.  I have flagged it for mod attention

Comment: I have a question: why was this question [Keyboard / mouse to use for a HTPC dedicated to the TV?](http://superuser.com/q/27891/58439) NOT closed, when mine was?

Comment: It is closed now. You're talking about a two year old question.

Comment: @Sathya it wasn't closed when I ran across is yesterday, random closed it after I mentioned it

Comment: When a shopping question comes around that needs to be closed, it will be. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

In its form it was/is of the type:

> I'm looking for a [product type] to replacing my existing and prefer to use products from [maker] compatible with my setup.

There is no learning that can be had here and is fishing for a list of products.

If you spot other questions of this nature and wonder why they're still open, it's because it's slipped through the community's collective eyeball. They will be closed when next spotted.

Comment: I agree with @random.